# Nemo 4.2.2 Mint Tina 19.2 - Show folders first

Tags: linux-mint, nemo

I've just migrated to Linux Mint 19.2 Tina from 18.1 Serena.

In the packaged Nemo (4.2.2), sorting icons alphabetically causes folders also to be sorted alphabetically in the list, instead of appearing as a complete cluster before files.

Is there any way to configure Nemo 4.2.2 to sort alphabetically but with all folders first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [page 6-56 of "Linux Mint 19.2: Desktops and Administration"](https://books.google.com/books?id=oSOpDwAAQBAJ&lpg=SA6-PA56-IA4&ots=McUaFGjZq5&dq=nemo%20preferences&pg=SA6-PA56-IA4#v=onepage&q=nemo%20preferences&f=false), there should be a "Sort folders before files" checkbox on the View tab of the Nemo Preferences dialog.

Comment: Nailed it, thanks.